# Checking if elements of array are present as keys in JSON and extracting value

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have two arrays.

```
simple_array = [:a, :b, :c]
complex_array = [{:a => 'apple'}, {:b => 'pie'}, {:c => 'fruit'}]
```

I need to check for each elements of simple_array if they are present as Keys of complex_array. If they are I need to extract the corresponding value. How can I do that using ruby ?

Comment: What's your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you could convert your `complex_array` to hash, then you could do this in one line using the `slice` method:

```
complex_array.reduce(:merge!).slice(*simple_array).values
```

The reason why you need the splat operator (the asterisk before `simple_array`) is because a typical use of `slice` looks like this:

```
# Good
{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}.slice(:a, :b)
# => {a: 1, b: 2}

# Bad
{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}.slice([:a, :b])
# => {}, because the key [:a, :b] does not exist
```

And splat in Ruby is used to transform the array [:a, :b] into a method call with two arguments. So the following are equivalent:

```
my_method(*[100, 200])
my_method(100, 200)
```

Btw, `slice` has a useful counterpart called `except`:

```
{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}.except(:a, :b)
# => {c: 3}
```

Comment: Neither `Hash` nor `Enumerable` have an instance method `slice` or `except`. Perhaps they are made available by Rails (I don't know), but there's no Rails tag. – Cary Swoveland 13 mins ago

Comment: You're right, these are in ActiveSupport::CoreExtensions::Hash.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
hashed = complex_array.reduce Hash.new, :merge
contains = simple_array.map { |v| !hashed[v].nil? }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this,

```
 simple_array.each do |a|
   p complex_array.map { |i| i[a] }.compact
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

First you can merge `complex_array` into one hash:

```
complex_hash = complex_array.reduce({}, &:merge)
```

Then you can check if a key exists any way you like. E.g. like this:

```
simple_values_array = complex_hash.values_at(*simple_array)
# => [apple, pie, fruit]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
simple_array = [:a, :b, :c, :d]
complex_array = [{a:'apple'}, {b: 'pie'}, {c: 'fruit'}, {e: 'yummy!'}]

missing = simple_array.dup
present = complex_array.select { |h| missing.delete h.first.first }
  #=> [{a:'apple'}, {b: 'pie'}, {c: 'fruit'}]
missing
  #=> [:d]
```